# How to make a Textfield in a form (html, jsp) accept only dd/mm/yyyy format without clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have a field in a jsp form page which accepts "from date" and "to date".. 
Now I know the script code which can be used to validate this using a submit button..
But my field currently accepts 10 characters in any form....eg: 28/07/2000 or 2807//2/00
It accepts numbers and any number of /...

But I want the field to accept 2 nos followed by / then 2 nos followed by / and the year..
Also is it possible to provide onpage validation like if date is 31/01/2000...then once 31 is typed by the user second set of nos allowed should be 01,03,05,07...& so on...
It should not allow 02,04..etc..
If date is 29/02/yyyy then yyyy should only leap years allowed... 
All this should be satisfied then only the cursor should move to other field & without refreshing the page...

Can this be achieved by ajax...
Since I need validation after 2 nos are entered,
If anyone has any idea I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction...

By the way I currently use this code for date validation....

```
    function checkdate(frmdt,todt){
    var validformat=/^\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}$/
    var returnval=false
       if(!validformat.test(frmdt.value)){
           alert("Invalid frmdt");
           document.form.frmdt.value="";
   }
       else if(!validformat.test(todt.value)){
       alert("Invalid Date 2");
        document.form.todt.value="";
   }
        else{
        var start = document.form.frmdt.value;
         var end = document.form.todt.value;

         var stDate = new Date(start);
        var enDate = new Date(end);
       var compDate = enDate - stDate;

        if(compDate >= 0)
       return true;
         else
            {
          alert("End date should be greater than start date.");
          return false;
         }
           }
         }
```

Comment: If HTML5 is fully supported then you could use ´<input type="date" />´, worked fine in Chrome but not Firfox, so not a solution at present, thought it worth a mention

Comment: most of my users use ie7 or 8 so it has to work on them too...

Comment: Then perhaps I would suggest that you consider dropdowns, where the first has the day, the next dropdown would be month and you can control what is in the list dependant on the first, then year on another which can be controlled likewise.

Comment: i tried that but some pages have 20 fields regarding dates,So it will frustrate the users to scroll everytime and choose date...I need to allow them to enter dates manually.. Dropdown wont work

Comment: So, you could then use a 3rd party library like jquery UI datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: thanks Xotic.. but imagine 20 datepickers in a single page... manual entry will be much faster...bcoz some dates are like date of birth which can go upto 1955..u have to scroll it 20 times..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [`onkeyup`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event, if you bind your validation function to this event it will run every time a key is released. You could use the [`onkeydown`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) event to store the current input value in a variable, and then the [`onkeyup`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event to run the validation. Then just edit the validation function to reset the input to the value stored in the variable when the key was pressed, if the validation is invalid. This way, as soon as a key is released, any invalid input would be undone.

It doesn't look like you are using jQuery at the moment (even though you have added the tag to your question). In case you want to use it you could use its [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) and [`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) methods instead.

You won't need any AJAX for this unless you want to do the validation using server side code and send the result back asynchronously, but that seems overkill for this fairly simple requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... I am a newbie and this is my first task on my job and I'm struggling... it would be helpful if you could give some example of how to use it....

Comment: Learning on the job :) I've always found that searching and trying things out myself has taught me the most. But do something like `<input type="text" onkeydown="saveCurrentValue(this);" onkeyup="validate(this);">`

Comment: And then implement a saveCurrentValue function which sticks the value into a temporary global variable, and a validate function which runs a validation based on the length of the value of the element passed to it (`this.value`). E.g.: if the length of the value is 3, then run a validation which only returns true if the first two characters of the value are numeric and the last character equals a slash. Then if that validation returns false, set the inputs value back to its original value which should be in the global variable.

Comment: `/^\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}$/` this bit in your JavaScript is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) which validates a full date. You would just need parts of that regular expression. E.g. running something like this on the inputs value: `/^\d{2}\-\$/` for when the length of the inputs value is 3 would validate that the value consists of 2 decimal numbers (\d{2}) followed by a `-` (\-) or a \ (\\). I'll leave the rest for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, then this solution should do what you have asked.

There are 3 states during input.

Red - definitely invalid

Yellow - partially valid

Green - definitely valid

HTML

```
<input id="date" type="text" maxlength="10" />
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/*global global */

(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    global.addEventListener("load", function onLoad() {
        global.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);

        document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
            var target = evt.target,
                value = target.value,
                parts = value.split("/"),
                day = parseInt(parts[0], 10),
                month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
                date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10) || 1600, month, day),
                dateCheck = day === date.getDate() && month === date.getMonth(),
                finalCheck = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(18|19|20)\d\d$/.test(value) && dateCheck;

            if (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}$/.test(value) || (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}(0[1-9]|1[012])\/{0,1}$/.test(value) && dateCheck) || finalCheck) {
                if (finalCheck) {
                    target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else {
                    target.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            } else {
                target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
        }, false);
    }, false);
}(window));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/LpVUP/)

Update: to address the additional question in the comments below

Javascript

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/*global global */

(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    global.addEventListener("load", function onLoad() {
        global.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);

        document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
            var target = evt.target,
                value = target.value,
                parts = value.split("/"),
                day = parseInt(parts[0], 10),
                month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
                date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10) || 1600, month, day),
                dateCheck = day === date.getDate() && month === date.getMonth(),
                finalCheck = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(18|19|20)\d\d$/.test(value) && dateCheck;

            if (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}$/.test(value) || (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}(0[1-9]|1[012])\/{0,1}$/.test(value) && dateCheck) || finalCheck) {
                if (finalCheck) {
                    target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else {
                    target.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            } else {
                target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                if (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}(0[1-9]|1[012])\/{0,1}$/.test(value)) {
                    if (!dateCheck) {
                        alert("incorrect number of days for month");
                    }
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }, false);
}(window));
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u4Sg8/)

Update: and example of event listener functions that can be used to give compatability with older non-standard Internet Explorer

Use this for adding listeners

```
function addEvt(obj, type, fni) {
    if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj['e' + type + fni] = fni;
        obj[type + fni] = function () {
            obj['e' + type + fni](window.event);
        };

        obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fni]);
    } else {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fni, false);
    }
}
```

Use this for removing listeners

```
function removeEvt(obj, type, fni) {
    if (obj.detachEvent) {
        obj.detachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fni]);
        obj[type + fni] = nul;
    } else {
        obj.removeEventListener(type, fni, false);
    }
}
```

In use

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/*global global */

(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    function addEvt(obj, type, fni) {
        if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj['e' + type + fni] = fni;
            obj[type + fni] = function () {
                obj['e' + type + fni](window.event);
            };

            obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fni]);
        } else {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fni, false);
        }
    }

    function removeEvt(obj, type, fni) {
        if (obj.detachEvent) {
            obj.detachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fni]);
            obj[type + fni] = nul;
        } else {
            obj.removeEventListener(type, fni, false);
        }
    }

    addEvt(global, "load", function onLoad() {
        removeEvt(global, "load", onLoad);

        addEvt(document.getElementById("date"), "keyup", function (evt) {
            var target = evt.target,
                value = target.value,
                parts = value.split("/"),
                day = parseInt(parts[0], 10),
                month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
                date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10) || 1600, month, day),
                dateCheck = day === date.getDate() && month === date.getMonth(),
                finalCheck = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(18|19|20)\d\d$/.test(value) && dateCheck;

            if (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}$/.test(value) || (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}(0[1-9]|1[012])\/{0,1}$/.test(value) && dateCheck) || finalCheck) {
                if (finalCheck) {
                    target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else {
                    target.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            } else {
                target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                if (/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/{0,1}(0[1-9]|1[012])\/{0,1}$/.test(value)) {
                    if (!dateCheck) {
                        alert("incorrect number of days for month");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}(window));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/V237D/)

Comment: Thanks it works....But when i try to put alert box instead of color...it gives error popup for every no. entered... how do i make the popup come up when the month entered doesnot match the no of days entered??

Comment: That would be in the "red" box, so add an if statement with the condition that you wish to match/check, and if matched then popup your alert. But this is not part of the original question.

Comment: thanks it worked on chrome and firefox but not on ie8...ie8 gives an error saying this object is not supported...I need it to work on ie. I tried enabling script, but did not work...

Comment: Thats because IE8 uses attachEvent instead of the standards addEventListener and detatchEvent instead of the standards removeEventListener. So you will need replace the event listeners with a function that works for both.

Comment: You will need to get used to the quirks of IE8 and IE7 if that is what you need to support, as you will find quite a number of differences like this.

Comment: Of course, this is what jQuery takes care of for you, so you could also use their event handling methods instead. But it pretty much does what I have just given you as an extra.

Comment: MDN also has a comparability shim for these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.removeEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.removeEventListener#Compatibility and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.removeEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.addEventListener#Compatibility