# how to validate and add date using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am working on a health website.

I am having a field called Last Menstrual Period, its a textbox which has to be filled in by doctor in format of YYYY-MM-DD.

What I want to do is, I have to add 281 days into the LMP date that the doctor will be entering in order to generate the Expected Delivery Date (Child Birth)

So I need followings thing to do:

1. The date entered should be in format of YYYY-MM-DD
2. It should be a valid date i.e. taking care of leap years and invalid dates like 2013-02-31 etc.
3. After generating the Expected Date of delivery (based on LMP that is entered), it should be displayed on screen.
4. As soon as the date is entered in the LMP textbox, these validations should be performed and the Expected Date Of Delivery is displayed inside a  tag below the LMP textbox

How can I do that? Here is what I have tried so far.

```
// Calculate Expected Date Of Delivery
$('#lmp_date').change(function()
{
    var lmp_entered = $this.val();

    if(lmp_entered)
    {
        // $('#edd').html('1');
    }
    else
    {
        // $('#edd').html('Please enter last menstrual date to calculate EDD');
```

Please help me how to implement these validations and display the date using jquery. I am a newbie in jquery so dont know much about it. Any small help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would highly recommend the Moment.js library. It makes all sorts of time-related functions easily accessible. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Take a look at this answer, I think it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459705/how-to-make-a-textfield-in-a-form-html-jsp-accept-only-dd-mm-yyyy-format-with/16464768#16464768

Answer (score 1):

for validation I don t recommend using another library especially for such a simple rule. if the rule is so strict just write your own and use it site wide.

For example block non-numberic entries to textbox and add dash "-" by your code in every 5th and 9th chars.

Then to validate check the length of text and dashed, use `split` to get year. month and day separately and convert it to date with `Date(txtYear,txtMonth,txtDay)` if your date's year, month and day are equals to your txtYear, Month and Day then it means it s a valid date. After that use the below to calculate birth date.

just use Date constructor like below

```
var delDate = new Date(year, month, day + 281)
```

Just don t forget months start 0 in JS so Jan = 0, Feb = 1 etc.