# javascript - regular expression to validate date in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, date, date-conversion

I'm not good at regular expression. I got code to validate dd/mm/yyyy format which also validates leap year, I tried to modify to get it work for mm/dd/yyyy, but they all failed.

Can some one change it to validate mm/dd/yyyy format?

Regular Expression:

> ^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(0[13578]|1[02])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)/(0[13456789]|1[012])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/02/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29/02/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$

**Answer**
Hi All, thanks for the help from all of you, finally parsing again the regular expression, i got my answer to validate mm/dd/yyyy format

Regular Expression:

> /^(((0[13578]|1[02])/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[13456789]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02/(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02/29/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g

Comment: Better try to construct Date object from the input string and if it is valid (not null), the date is valid. Because issues like leap year and number of days in a month will be solved easily

Comment: Using a regular expression is a bad idea here. People fail to get leap year calculations right at the best of times - trying to do it in a regex would be horrible.

Comment: Have a look at this answer to give you some alternative ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16464768/592253

Comment: You should not be asking if someone can change your code for you! http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I need the above regular expression to be changed to mm/dd/yyyy format, because the javascript date function takes it in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: Parse the string yourself and feed in the component parts, see [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: There are lots of examples here on SO for dealing with conversion, here is another reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093796/date-formatting-with-without-moment-js/17094020#17094020

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LSsMc/

Comment: Here's another: [Test if date is Valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/test-if-date-is-valid/5812341#5812341).

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
function validateDate(testdate) {
    var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    return date_regex.test(testdate);
}
```

But better to use regular expression use `Date object` from your date string and then validate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to validate leap year date as well

Comment: it didnt do that..??have you checked it..?

Comment: Leap year is not going to be in a different format is it??

Comment: I think so @Connor may need to change it little bit.

Comment: In jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LSsMc/