# Validate date on keypress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is the regex :

```
 pattern =/^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$/;
```

Hi guys, I found a simple regex for date format , no checking for leap year, but on my fiddle I can still input other invalid characters.
Please see my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cnb0weux/).

Comment: The regex in your example is for matching a full date format, not restricting what can be typed. Also, you are using a double equals for the assignment of the pattern.

Comment: Typo error on double equal sign,so validation for date should be on  leave on input?

Comment: Sorry my first message was a bit short. If I understand the question correctly, you would like the user to enter the date in exactly a specific format, as they type it. So they couldn't enter letters or anything, just two numbers, a hyphen, two more numbers, a hyphen, and then four numbers. Is that the goal?

Comment: Yes sir, that's my goal,by  using keypress event. @getWeberForStackExchange

Comment: Nice regex from tbh__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ruhaxo/9/edit

Your code made me a little uncomfortable, so I tried to write this more simply so that it would be easier to read, you can pull out the part that you need, which I really think is just the event.preventDefault() when there is a match. Just to expand, as well: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes you are looking for char codes not the literal numbers.

```
    $('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
      var leng = $(this).val().length;

      if (window.event) {
        code = e.keyCode;
      }else {
        code = e.which;
      };

      var allowedCharacters = [49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,48,45];
      var isValidInput = false;

      for (var i = allowedCharacters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(allowedCharacters[i] == code){
          isValidInput = true;
        } 
      };

      if(isValidInput === false || /* Can only input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 or - */
       (code == 45 && (leng < 2 || leng > 5 || leng == 3 || leng == 4)) ||
       ((leng == 2 || leng == 5) && code !== 45) || /* only can hit a - for 3rd pos. */
        leng == 10 ) /* only want 10 characters "12-45-7890" */
      {

        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

    });
```

You can also do this with an object, rather than an Array. Which is a little easier to read:

```
    $('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
      var leng = $(this).val().length;

      if (window.event) {
        code = e.keyCode;
      }else {
        code = e.which;
      };

      var allowedCharacters = {49:1,50:2,51:3,52:4,53:5,54:6,55:7,56:8,57:9,48:0,45:'-'}; /* KeyCodes for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,- */

      if(typeof allowedCharacters[code] === 'undefined'|| /* Can only input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 or - */
         (code == 45 && (leng < 2 || leng > 5 || leng == 3 || leng == 4)) ||
         ((leng == 2 || leng == 5) && code !== 45) || /* only can hit a - for 3rd pos. */
          leng == 10 ) /* only want 10 characters "12-45-7890" */
      {

        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

    });
```

EDITED:

Please be careful with this, I haven't fully tested this, but I edited the regex from the post mentioned, if you have this in addition to one of the other choices above, (this happens on keyup after the other checks have been made) this would validate the date in the format mm-dd-yyyy please check that it works properly, I tried 02-29-2008, the first leap year I could think of, and it worked, but I would recommend testing it more since it has been modified.

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(e){

  /* From:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503043/javascript-regular-expression-to-validate-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format
  and
  http://jsfiddle.net/LSsMc/
  */

  var thisVal = $(this).val();
  var leng = thisVal.length;

  var reg = new RegExp(/^(((0[13578]|1[02])\-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[13456789]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02\-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02\-29\-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g);
  if(leng == 10){
    if(reg.test(thisVal)){
      console.log('Valid Date');
    }else {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @tbh__ i will try your code.so I can give question later.thanks

Comment: Cool, and just FYI, this doesn't prevent people from pasting a random string into the box, but that's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: your code help me alot, but is there anyway I can add some checking for valid date,leap year and right days count of a month? Id like also to add regex for that.

Comment: yah, I know i different event could handle that.thanks

Comment: Or when I want to use regex for valid date I need to call it on just when user leave the input and my keypress is for date format only?

Comment: I appended a regex solution.

Comment: I have it on keyup, but you could add blur etc to it.

Comment: Im avail to input `12--------`

Comment: I added a fix for this.

Comment: It's getting a little unwieldy and could be optimized though.